# Checking if a number is limit (endpoint of range) in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, endpoint

I have data in excel that looks like this:

```
4\10
7\10
2\3
9\9
8\8
1\5
2\4
2\5
```

If 1-st number equals to 1 or to upper limit of the 2-nd number after slash, it is classified as 'yes'. Otherwise it is classified as 'no'. I want to check if a number before slash is endpoint of range number after slash. For example:

[image]

What formula to put in B column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edited to fix errors on values like 10/11 or 101/111 ...*

`=IF(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1)="1","yes",IF(LEFT(A1,FIND("/",A1)-1)=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("/",A1)),"yes","no"))`

Comment: Try an input of 10\11; your formula fails.

Comment: Thanks @D_Bester ... Just realized that and working on a fix now

Answer (score 4):

This works also for more digit numbers:

```
=IF(OR(MID(A1,1,FIND("\",A1)-1)="1",MID(A1,1,FIND("\",A1)-1)=MID(A1,FIND("\",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("\",A1))),"yes","no")
```

Answer (score 2):

Break it down to build up your formula:
Use `LEFT(A2,FIND("\",A2)-1)` to get the left number (as text).
Use `MID(A2,FIND("\",A2)+1,50)` to get the right number (as text).
Then compare using `=IF(OR(` left number = "1" (as text)`,` left number `=` right number (both as text) `),"Yes","No")`

=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,FIND("\",A2)-1)="1",LEFT(A2,FIND("\",A2)-1)=MID(A2,FIND("\",A2)+1,10)),"Yes","No")